# c, creating children and wait()

Tags: c, linux, wait

I thought the wait(4) instruction would force the parent process to wait for it's children to finish but does not, actually the process "hijo2" launches first, the "padre" second and "hijo1" third

```
int variable = 6;

if (fork() == 0){
    variable = variable -3;
    printf("\nLa variable del proceso hijo1 contiene %d\n", variable);
} else  if (fork()==0){
    variable = variable -3;
    printf("\nLa variable del proceso hijo2 contiene %d\n", variable);      
} else {
    wait(2);//para esperar a que terminen los hijos
    variable = variable +5;
    printf("\nLa variable del proceso padre contiene %d\n", variable);
}
exit(0);
```

Comment: What is the argument `4` to wait supposed to mean? Doesn't wait take a pointer to in as argument?

Comment: sorry, I thought it was the time to wait (my teacher taught me so), Thomas got the solution down on the Answers section, thanks!

Comment: No, `wait(2)` is wrong too! It's just the way the function is sometimes written, to show that it is from section 2 in the manual, that is, a system call. Use `wait(NULL);` if you aren't interested in the status.

Comment: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/singlepage/bgipc.html#fork

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait` waits for *one* child to terminate. You need to call it twice.